# Brightest Pixels around Edges in Edge Detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I noticed that my edges has the brightest pixels around them as the example picture shows.

[image: Bright Spots around edges]

I was wondering: What causes this effect? Can this can affect a subpixel edge detection?

Can someone help clear this out or give references?

[image: Fitting Edge Curve]

Comment: What do you mean by "my edges"? Where are these images coming from?

Comment: Are your images compressed?

Comment: @Abhi25t the first image is actually from the internet, but the same occurs my video capture from a stationary USB camera. I just thought that it ilustrates the effect well, in the website there is no comment about it. The second is mine and the curve that I extract from the highlighted blue pixels. The orange dot is the fitted edge. The red dot is the final edge with an angle compensation that I do later on.

Comment: @eldesgraciado the image are compressed in MJPEG.

Comment: Most likely what you are seeing are compression artifacts produced by the JPEG compression algorithm. You have at least two options: Use lossless (PNG) images (note that simply saving your already compressed image as PNG won't magically reconstruct the missing information) or, and this depends on your application, threshold the input image and work with a binary input instead.

Comment: you can clean these up with median blur

Comment: @IanChu median filter seems like a way to go. In a quick test it seemed to help, I will look deeper into this. Thank you.

Comment: @eldesgraciado My current camera does not allow me to change the compression but I will test other camera later on. Thank you.